# Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. (used ~/)

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-error

I am receiving this error message "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory." but all I have is a simple Response.Redirect.

Here is the code:

.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="newCust" class="mainButton left button" runat="server" Text="new customer" OnClick="New_Customer" />
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void New_Customer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Customer/New_Customer.aspx");
}
```

And my URL points to the correct directory:

```
http://localhost:59415/Customer/New_Customer.aspx
```

I have even tried using a link where I literally clicked to the specific directory:

```
<a href="Customer/New_Customer.aspx" class="left">
    <asp:Label ID="newCust" runat="server" Text="new customer" CssClass="mainButtom button"></asp:Label>
</a>
```

ERROR:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
>   Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace: 
>   [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.]
>      System.Web.Util.UrlPath.ReduceVirtualPath(String path) +9862804
>      System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Reduce(String path) +50

I have looked at the questions asked previously and most people solved it with "~" yet for me that is not the case. I need a solution/ workaround to this problem. What is wrong in my code?

The error persists even on my the hosting service (the site is online too) so it can't be my machine.

Comment: Perhaps the error is in NewCustomer.aspx. Does that page have any resolveurls?

Comment: No, that's not it. i commented out the code on page load and tested that. When running the steps, i find that it breaks after the MasterPage Page load (which is blank). I've been fiddling around with it the whole day

Comment: After replying to your comment, I went to have a look at the Master page's .aspx and guess what? There was a "../" reference to font-awesome -_- . Your comment actually did help out in a way

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same sort of problem when i was adding a master page and it got resolved by giving the correct path of my CSS files used in that master page, hope this answer helps someone.